# Cypress read data of ag-grid that contains horizontal scrolling

Tags: scroll, cypress, ag-grid

I have an `ag-grid` table and I need to read the data of all the columns inside of it in a Cypress test.

The `ag-grid` contains horizontal scrolling.

My issue is the data of the columns that needs horizontal scroll to be visible are not read by the Cypress query.

Is there any way to read all the columns?.

I tried to read the data using:

```js
cy.get('#myGrid').getAgGridData()
```

but the data of the columns that need scroll are not returned.

Answer (score 2):

That is true because AG Grid uses column virtualization by default. For testing purposes, you will need to turn it off.

Use `suppressColumnVirtualisation` property for this.

Answer (score 0):

There's an [issue](https://github.com/kpmck/cypress-ag-grid/issues/11) on the `cypress-ag-grid` repository where this limitation is discussed.

I have posted a [workaround](https://github.com/kpmck/cypress-ag-grid/issues/11#issuecomment-1615266941), inspired by [@mashi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3519246/mashi)'s answer, I have applied in a React project I work on.